# Include a php file in another php file wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I am trying to include a file in an another file, but nothing. No error. First I included my main file.

```
include('inc/onefolder/mymainfile.php');
```

And then I try to include secondary files in this file (`mymainfile.php`).

```
include('inc/onefolder/anotherfolder/secondaryfile.php');
```

Comment: Have you tried `include('anotherfolder/secondaryfile.php');` ?

Comment: Yes i try it too but nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to include absolute path of your file.
Use it:

```
$file = ABSPATH."wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/your-file.php";
```

in your case:

```
//main thing is to use ABSPATH
$file = ABSPATH."inc/onefolder/anotherfolder/secondaryfile.php";    
require $file; // use include if you want.

$file = ABSPATH."wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/inc/onefolder/anotherfolder/secondaryfile.php";
```

Check it out, please note, you should give the exact path as written on above line. Make it clear.

Comment: When i use require() i got a blank page. Thank you for your time @Haider

Comment: you can also use include instead of require. It depends upon your requirements. But the way to include file is via absolute path.

Comment: You welcome brother and thanks to Stackoverflow Community.

Answer (score 6):

When you use PHP `include` or `require` in a WordPress plugin is a good idea to use WordPress specific functions to get the absolute path of the file. You can use [plugin_dir_path](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/):

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/onefolder/mymainfile.php');
```

Plugins directory is not always at wp-content/plugins as we can read in [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories):

> It's important to remember that WordPress allows users to place their
>   wp-content directory anywhere they want, so you must never assume that
>   plugins will be in wp-content/plugins, or that uploads will be in
>   wp-content/uploads, or that themes will be in wp-content/themes.

So, using plugin_dir_path() assures that `include` will always point to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

- I think your path in secondary file incorrect.
- Try this include('anotherfolder/secondaryfile.php');

Comment: I try this but is the same as before but thank you for your time @Jaswant Singh